# Does NSMutableArray's -removeLastObject RELEASE the object?

Tags: iphone, uikit, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm talking about methods like -removeAllObjects, -removeLastObject, etc for NSMutableArray. The documentation only says that these methods 'remove' the object from the array. Are the removed objects released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does.  Any remove invokes the release of the removed `NSObject`.

The [`NSArray` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) specifies:

> Arrays maintain strong references to
>   their contents—in a managed memory
>   environment, each object receives a
>   retain message before its id is added
>   to the array and a release message
>   when it is removed from the array or
>   when the array is deallocated. If you
>   want a collection with different
>   object ownership semantics, consider
>   using CFArray Reference,
>   NSPointerArray, or NSHashTable
>   instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are released. You can see that the contained object is released by overriding `release` in an object you've placed in the container. Call the superclass's `release` method and set a breakpoint on it. You'll see that it's released.

I had originally stated that I thought the objects were auto-released. Turns out I believe I'm wrong about that.